# What should be the datasource while uploading file to the real server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

This is what I have tried to do

```
<add name="str" connectionString="Data Source=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX;Initial Catalog=immenseshop; Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: It should be the correct IP or domain name of the sql server

Comment: IP of domain? Say i bought www.the.com.Then by IP do u mean IP of www.the.com.

Comment: What about the domain name of sql server?